# Why we generally hash the 'key' before applying it on any encryption algorithm?

Tags: security, encryption, hash, password-encryption

I am making a Password Manager application for android to store and retrieve passwords whenever needed. I want to first encrypt my password and then store it in my database. I saw a tutorial where he first hash the 'key' and then apply it on the AES algorithm to encrypt the password. I am unable to understand why he does so.

Comment: You may be misusing the terms "encrypt" and "hash" here. By "hash" I suspect you mean "stretch" (which includes hashing as a step). You may also be misusing "key" (this is often confused with "password"). In order to answer the question, you'll need to point to the actual steps that were recommended. Note that building a password manager (or any encryption system) is an advanced topic that is difficult to implement correctly, and unfortunately much of the code commonly found online is incorrect. You should expect to do a lot of research.

Comment: BTW, if you want an excellent introduction to this topic, along with a best-in-class security design, see AgileBit's white paper explaining step-by-step how they implement 1Password. https://1password.com/files/1Password%20for%20Teams%20White%20Paper.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would guess that the "key" is a passphrase of some kind, which is known only to the password manager, and which encrypts all passwords -- the passwords are encrypted so they can later be decrypted and returned.

If that is the case, do not hash the key. It's better to "derive" an encryption key from it. For example, the "key" may be "snowfallsinthesummertime". HKDF is an example of a key derivation algorithm which can take this "key" and produce a strong encryption key which is then used with AES encryption to encrypt the password. That's the only way I can explain the "hashing the key" of your question.

Furthermore, along with encrypting the password, it's a good idea to prevent tampering of the encrypted data. A good way to do that is to chose the GCM mode of AES encryption which includes an "authentication tag" which would detect tampering.

Comment: Isn't HKDF too fast to protect against dictionary attacks? I see it as an algorithm simply for stretching limited key material into multiple keys, while a password-based KDF like Argon2 or PBKDF2 is necessary to securely convert a human-selected password to a key.